# Cakephp Tree Behavior moveUp()/moveDown() returns false

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So I've implemented [CakePHP's Tree Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior)

`$this->Model->moveUp(4, 1)` (or whatever I pass in) returns false. I have copy and pasted from the book to try and troubleshoot this.

I've verified that a record exists with the id in the database and that it can be moved both up and down in the tree, however the function always returns false.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: According to API this method will return false only If the node is the first child, or is a top level node with no previous node. Is it?

Comment: It shouldn't be. I've tried with various records. I'm not near the code now but from what I can remember I tried it with a middle child of 3 whose parent was a top level node, a node without siblings but had grandparents and grandchildren, my second of two top level nodes and a node with no siblings 6 levels deep with each parent node being the only node in the branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try `TreeBehavior::verify()` and `TreeBehavior::reorder` in this case, to make shure the tree structure is correct.